# Regarding getting time in milliseconds

Tags: c, time, qnx

I am working on logger using C language on QNX platform using Momnetics to print time in following format

2010-11-02 14:45:15.000

I able to get date, hour, minutes, and seconds using

```
 time(&timeSpec);
 struct tm gmt;
 int iSysTimeSec = timeSpec;
 gmtime_r((time_t *)&iSysTimeSec, &gmt);
 sprintf(&MsgStamp[0], SYS_MSG_STAMP_PRINTF_FORMAT, gmt.tm_year+1900, gmt.tm_mon + 1, gmt.tm_mday, gmt.tm_hour, gmt.tm_min, gmt.tm_sec, iSysTimeMs );
```

Question is how do i get milliseconds granularity using QNX Momentics.

I tried to get granulaity for milliseconds using QNX specific 
int iSysTimeMs = ( (ClockCycles () * 1000) / SYSPAGE_ENTRY(qtime)->cycles_per_sec ) % 1000;

but i want to do this POSIX way so that it is portable. How do we do this?

Thanks!
Venkata

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In QNX6 You can use the clock_gettime to have the max granularity
allowed by system.

```
struct timespec start;
clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);
```

Comment: can u pls elaborate how to get milliseconds, i am seeing only seconds and nano seconds.

Comment: How about dividing the nanoseconds by 1000?

Comment: @DevSolar: ... that would yield microseconds, not milliseconds. @Venkata:  Are you serious!?  `millisec = nanosec / 1000000 ;`

Comment: @Clifford don't be so quick to dismiss as converting from nano to milli is non trivial. For example, what happens when converting 1000 nano seconds (long int) to 1000/1000000 milliseconds (long int or float or...???)

Comment: @puk:  In that case you would get zero milliseconds, which is exactly correct - the question explicitly calls for *"millisecond granularity"*. The required arithmetic *is* trivial, the nature of machine integer arithmetic is a different matter.  In some cases you might want to round to the nearest integer rather than truncate downward, but that is by no means a given.  It can be done by `(ns + 500000) / 1000000`, but even in that case 1000 nanosecond is still zero milliseconds. Depending on the configuration `CLOCK_REALTIME` may not even support the required resolution.

Comment: @Clifford I didn't mean it in the sense that 'screw you, you are a moron', just that from a non pro looking at this, you might wonder if dividing an integer so as to generate a non integer might crash the Matrix and cause a rift in the space time continuum.

Comment: @Puk:  On the contrary, I think you may have raised more fear uncertainty and doubt on this than it really deserved (three years after the event too).

Answer (score 0):

The `gettimeofday()` system call will return a structure holding the current Unix time in seconds and the number of microseconds belonging to the current second.

To get the total number of microseconds:

```
struct timeval tv;
gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
u_int64_t now = tv.tv_sec * 1000000ULL + tv.tv_usec;
```

Comment: how do i fit your anwer to my question 14:45:15.000, here how do i replace last three zeros which i have to fill with micro seconds